# Should i delete webpack and other libraries after bundling?

Tags: npm, webpack, bundle

NPM donwloads a lot of files needed for the webpack/libraries. From what i understand, webpack generates a one single bundle file, that contains all code for script working. After that, when i finish building my app, do i need to keep all those jquery/react files and webpack itself? Or should i just delete them?

Comment: Hi, please explain what you mean by "finish" in this case. Do you never intend to make any updates to this project, thus not requiring those `node_modules`?

Comment: Hello. For example, i've made a website for a customer. Yes, maybe there will be updates to the project in future. Should i leave all of these files, or give him only the "product"? What i'm trying to say is i'm a bit confused by how many files NPM downloads - there is about 5k files. I'm not sure if i will use all of them in the project. Would'nt they be just extra weight, files to maintain?

Comment: Ok, well stated, they are often extra baggage. Let me give you a way to get rid of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common practice to make a project portable/shareable by following these steps;

- Create a `package.json` and ensure to capture all `dependencies`,`devDependencies` and/or `peerDependencies`.
- Add/commit this `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files to your version control
- Create a `.gitignore` file and add `node_modules` to it (in essence, this cuts out that baggage)
- For production purpose (e.g. to be shared with client finished product), build the project (which often results into a small files, often within `/build` or `dist`). And then you can always push that build file to AWS or Heroku or the clients' servers.

What does the above help you achieve?
You can easily start the project using any machine, as long as you run `npm install` which reads from your `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! It was extremely helpful for me. I'll work and study on methods you described :)

Comment: Alright, please respond here in case you find any methods that we should add to this list to help others also.